# Gesture recognisers for UIImage

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uigesturerecognizer

All,

I have studied Gesture Recognisers and I have placed one in Interface builder and I am going to wire it all up. I have also enabled 'User Interaction Enabled' in IB on the UIImage.

How can I make the UIImage larger according to how far the finger is swiped down on the screen.

How can I make the UIImage larger in the UIView that it sites in ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me, I'm using UIPinchGestureRecognizer, which is use as a default if you want to scale the view:

```
@IBAction func handlePinch(recognizer : UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
  recognizer.view!.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(recognizer.view!.transform, recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale)
  // Reset recognizer scale
  recognizer.scale = 1
}
```

If you want to use swipe gesture, you need to calculate swipe difference between start point and current swipe point and convert it to scale value you required.